# Telerik MVC grid-How to set default row selected

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, telerik

Is it possible to render a Grid with one row selected as default (set the right page number and highlight the row)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For highlighting, try using the "OnRowDataBound" event

```
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("onRowDataBound"))
```

with something like

```
function onRowDataBound(e) {
    var myId = $('#MyId').val();

    if (e.dataItem.Id == myId)
        e.row.className = 't-state-selected';
}
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to set the correct initial page number. [This bloke](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/loading-correct-page-for-selected-row.aspx) might be on to something.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Grid RowAction method, eg:

```
.RowAction(row => row.Selected = row.DataItem.CustomerCode.Equals(ViewBag.ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps possible if you iterate in the grid source, locate the row which has to be selected in it, than use a formula to detect on which page will be displayed, and finally change the page index on initial load and select it.